# Where do I place the logic for validating and transforming a request to a model object in DRF?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I have a working python app that I'm trying to transform in a webapp using django and django rest. For now, I just want to do a post request containing some data:

```
{
"orderside" :"long",
"symbol" : "BTCUSDT",
"leverage" : "20",
"entry_price" : "100",
"order_cost" : "5.2",
"sl_price" :"99.4",
"tp_price" : "101.2"
}
```

Based on this data, I need to do some validity checks and some calculations. If the data is valid, I want to persist the results as a Trade entity in the database (no 1 to 1 mapping from request to model).

This is the model for a Trade:

```
from django.db import models

class Trade(models.Model):
    created_datetime = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    entry_filled_datetime = models.DateTimeField()
    tp_sl_filled_datetime = models.DateTimeField()
    orderside = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    symbol = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    leverage = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
    entry_price = models.FloatField()
    quantity = models.FloatField()
    sl_price = models.FloatField()
    tp_price = models.FloatField()
    entry_id = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    tp_id = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    sl_id = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    state = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
    side = models.CharField(max_length=10)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['created_datetime']
```

Where do I have to put the code for validation of the request data , and where do I put the calculation logic?
Can I put both in the view class, like below? And where does a serializer fit in to this?

```
class TradeView(APIView):

    def post(self, request, format=None):

        if check_valid_request_data(request.data):

            # do_calculations here and return model instance?
            trade = do_calculations(request.data)  # tuple for example

            # save trade to db
            trade.save()

            return Response(status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)

        return Response(status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)



    def check_valid_request_data(data):
        # validation checklist


    def do_calculations(data):
        # calculate trade parameters like quantity etc
        # return model instance from calculations and fields in request
```

Answer (score 0):

You would create a class, `TradeSerializer()`. Validation would be done in the `validate` method of that class. Creation of the new Trade object would done in the `create` method of your TradeSerializer class.

[This](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/1-serialization/#writing-regular-django-views-using-our-serializer) page should answer all of your other follow-up questions.

Comment: Thanks it worked, I used [this](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/) for some more info on serializers